# c# linq filtering based on given list

Tags: c#, linq

I have situation where I need to use C# Linq and filter Tags based on admin scopes but stuck with one problem that I cannot find a proper way either its a problem with OR operator or I'm doing something wrong with .All().

Basically I need something like that:
Read scope - must match all
Then Delete scope should match only one or multiple,
Then Write scope should match only one or multiple

I wrote comments on code maybe someone have better idea how to filter it?

Here is example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public class Admin
    {
        public List<string> ReadScopes { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public List<string> DeleteScopes { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public List<string> WriteScopes { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public List<Rules> Rules { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rules
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public Scope Scope;
    }

    public enum Scope
    {
        Read, Delete, Write
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tags = new List<Tag>
            {
                new Tag 
                { 
                    Name = "Tag0", 
                    // NO RULES AVAILABLE FOR ALL
                    Rules = new List<Rules>() 
                },
                new Tag { Name = "Tag1", Rules = new List<Rules>() 
                {
                    //MUST MATCH ALL:
                    new Rules { Value = "Read_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Read },
                    new Rules { Value = "Read_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Read }
                }},
                
                new Tag { Name = "Tag2", Rules = new List<Rules>()
                {
                    //MUST MATCH ALL:
                    new Rules { Value = "Read_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Read },
                    new Rules { Value = "Read_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Read },
                    // AND THEN MUST MATCH ONE OF THESE:
                    new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
                    new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
                }},
                
                new Tag { Name = "Tag3", Rules = new List<Rules>()
                {
                    //MUST MATCH ALL:
                    new Rules { Value = "Read_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Read },
                    new Rules { Value = "Read_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Read },
                    // AND THEN MUST MATCH ONE OF THESE:
                    new Rules { Value = "Write_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Write },
                    new Rules { Value = "Write_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Write },
                }},

                new Tag { Name = "Tag4", Rules = new List<Rules>()
                {
                    //MUST MATCH ALL:
                    new Rules { Value = "Read_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Read },
                    new Rules { Value = "Read_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Read },
                    // AND THEN MUST MATCH ONE OF THESE:
                    new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
                    new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
                    // AND THEN MUST MATCH ONE OF THESE:
                    new Rules { Value = "Write_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Write },
                    new Rules { Value = "Write_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Write },
                }},
                
                new Tag { Name = "Tag5", Rules = new List<Rules>()
                {
                    // ONLY MUST MATCH ONE OF THESE:
                    new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
                    new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
                    // AND THEN MUST MATCH ONE OF THESE:
                    new Rules { Value = "Write_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Write },
                    new Rules { Value = "Write_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Write },
                }},
                
                new Tag { Name = "Tag6", Rules = new List<Rules>()
                {
                    // ONLY MUST MATCH ONE OF THESE:
                    new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
                    new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
                }},
                
                new Tag { Name = "Tag7", Rules = new List<Rules>()
                {
                    // ONLY MUST MATCH ONE OF THESE:
                    new Rules { Value = "Write_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Write },
                    new Rules { Value = "Write_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Write },
                }},
            };

            //GET Tag0, Tag1
            var admin = new Admin
            {
                ReadScopes = new List<string> { "Read_With_1Scope", "Read_With_2Scope" },
            };

            //GET Tag0, Tag1, Tag2
            var admin1 = new Admin
            {
                ReadScopes = new List<string> { "Read_With_1Scope", "Read_With_2Scope" },
                DeleteScopes = new List<string> { "Delete_With_1Scope" },
            };
            //.....
            //.....

            //GET Tag0, Tag7
            var admin2 = new Admin
            {
                WriteScopes = new List<string> { "Write_With_1Scope" },
            };

            //ADMIN1 TEST - PROBLEM WITH TAG2
            var available_tags = tags
                .Where(tag => tag.Rules.All(rule => 
                    admin1.ReadScopes.Any(value => rule.Value == value) 
                    ||
                    admin1.DeleteScopes.Any(value => rule.Value == value)
                    ||
                    admin1.WriteScopes.Any(value => rule.Value == value)
                    ));
            foreach (var available_tag in available_tags)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(available_tag.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your original code goes through all the tags and filter to take only the tags that satisfy the condition for all the rules in that tag (`tag.Rules.All(...)`) and obviously not what you want

To fix it, you need to filter rules by scope for each tag, and use `All()` if you want all the filtered rules to match, or `Any()` if any of them to match. Something like this:

```
var available_tags = tags
    .Where(tag => 
        tag.Rules.Where(r => r.Scope == Scope.Read).All(r => admin1.ReadScopes.Contains(r.Value))) &&
        (tag.Rules.Where(r => r.Scope == Scope.Write).Count() == 0 || tag.Rules.Where(r => r.Scope == Scope.Write).Any(r => admin1.WriteScopes.Contains(r.Value))) &&
        (tag.Rules.Where(r => r.Scope == Scope.Delete).Count() == 0 || tag.Rules.Where(r => r.Scope == Scope.Delete).Any(r => admin1.DeleteScopes.Contains(r.Value))));
```

the checking for `Count() == 0` is necessary because if there are no rules for that scope, `Any()` will return false.

To make it a bit nicer and more efficient, I'll create some helper methods like:

```
private static bool MatchAllRules(List<string> adminRules, List<Rules> allRules, Scope scope)
{
    var rulesByScope = allRules.Where(r => r.Scope == scope).ToList();
    return rulesByScope.All(r => adminRules.Contains(r.Value));
}

private static bool MatchAnyRule(List<string> adminRules, List<Rules> allRules, Scope scope)
{
    var rulesByScope = allRules.Where(r => r.Scope == scope).ToList();
    if (rulesByScope.Count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return rulesByScope.Any(r => adminRules.Contains(r.Value));
}
```

and use them like this:

```
var available_tags = tags
    .Where(tag => 
        MatchAllRules(admin1.ReadScopes, tag.Rules, Scope.Read) &&
        MatchAnyRule(admin1.WriteScopes, tag.Rules, Scope.Write) &&
        MatchAnyRule(admin1.DeleteScopes, tag.Rules, Scope.Delete));
```

Comment: thanks for such a great and clear explanation! I was thinking in different way and even forgot that I can filter those scopes to make it easier, thanks again for help!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstand, but let's have a look. You say admin1, should receive this tag:

```
        new Tag { Name = "Tag2", Rules = new List<Rules>()
        {
            //MUST MATCH ALL:
            new Rules { Value = "Read_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Read },
            new Rules { Value = "Read_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Read },
            // AND THEN MUST MATCH ONE OF THESE:
            new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_1Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
            new Rules { Value = "Delete_With_2Scope", Scope = Scope.Delete },
        }},
```

So in order for admin1 to receive this tag, he must satisfy ALL conditions to receive this tag. However, he's missing Delete_with_2Scope, so since he doesn't satisfy that condition, he does not receive the tag.

If you add that scope in his delete scopes for example, then he should receive tag2.

Comment: Hi, actually thats where problem is, admin1 should only match all ReadScopes, but with Write/Delete scopes he should only match one them or all, I mean he don't need to have all delete scopes only match one of them (Delete_With_1Scope) there is no need to have (Delete_With_2Scope)